# Custom text transformation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Hi: I want to make a vector graphics plot in matplotlib like the following image:

[image]

Especially I want to use latex string and a custom 2x2 transformation matrix [[a, b], [c, d]] to transform the text. I checked the matplotlib documents but found no examples. As far as I know, postsctript allows Affine matrix to transform the texts? so I think this should be possible with matplotlib. Anyone knows how to do this? thanks!

Comment: I don't think matplotlib deals with vector graphics. There is a library to deal with SVG, you can check https://pypi.org/project/drawSvg/

Comment: Doesn't matplotlib has backends agg, ps and pdf that support saving images as vector formats? Sadly python libs like drawSvg and scgwrite do not allow embedding latex strings.

Comment: Oh okay, I should not say that, I actually don't have much knowledge matplotlib dealing with vector graphics.